# What kind of convex washer goes on the brake pads?

Tags: brakes, brake-pads

I forgot to tighten up my brake pads before I went for a ride today, and I lost the convex washers when the nut came loose? Could anyone tell me where I could find replacement washers for the brake pad? I checked at lowes and attempted to google them, but I have no idea how these washers are sized.

Comment: Local bike shop will have them.

Comment: While you can get away with non-critical parts from a hardware shop, often bike bolts are high tensile and the retail bolts are plain old mild steel.  A hardware shop might have cup washers but they're unlikely to have convex and concave washers for bike brakes.   In the future you can save your old ones for this kind of oopsi-dent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buy yourself a set of new brake pads.  They come with all the washers and nuts.  When the current pads wear out, move all the washers and bolts to the newer pads, which you keep safe till you need them.

Or just fit new pads now.